# gnuplot input file 7 columns with decimals

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I am trying to graph the following data file:

```
61.0       16.4       100.0      28.6       28.6       12.2       12.2
59.0       25.4       100.0      21.4       21.4       11.8       11.8
69.0       15.9       100.0      35.7       35.7       11.5       11.5
59.0       23.7       100.0      23.4       23.4       11.8       11.8
49.0       20.4       100.0      18.0       18.0       9.8        9.8
84.0       13.1       90.9       50.8       50.8       16.8       16.8
59.0       16.9       100.0      22.6       22.6       11.8       11.8
71.0       16.9       100.0      32.8       32.8       14.2       14.2
68.0       19.1       100.0      26.2       26.2       13.6       13.6
91.0       13.2       100.0      51.6       51.6       18.2       18.2
57.0       22.8       100.0      29.4       29.4       11.4       11.4
52.0       26.9       100.0      17.8       17.8       10.4       10.4
55.0       21.8       100.0      32.2       32.2       11.0       11.0
68.0       19.1       100.0      29.8       29.8       13.6       13.6
50.0       22.0       100.0      19.0       19.0       10.0       10.0
149.0      12.1       66.7       111.2      111.2      29.8       29.8
69.0       20.3       100.0      29.8       29.8       13.8       13.8
```

I am very new to gnuplot I cant seem to figure out what the correct code will be to get this graph:

I was trying something like this:

```
gnuplot> set output 'datastore1.png'                                                              
gnuplot> plot 'desktop1.dat' using 0:1 title "totalio" with lines, 'desktop1.dat' using 0:2 title "readpercentage" with lines, 'desktop1.dat' using 0:3 title "cachehitpercentage" with lines, 'desktop1.dat' using 0:4 title "currentkbpersecond" with lines, 'desktop1.dat' using 0:5 title "maximumkbpersecond" with lines, 'desktop1.dat' using 0:6 title "currentiopersecond" with lines, 'desktop1.dat' using 0:7 title "maximumiopersecond" with lines
gnuplot> quit
```

However the graph is not exactly correct.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to plot here, but I think the error is that you are using the zero-th column for the 'using' command which does not exist. Rather use this

```
p 'desktop1.dat' u 1:2, 'desktop1.dat' u 1:3
```

**edit**

So when you are plotting against time, you might want to add another column to the data that you read in from the file such that you have

```
15       61.0       16.4       100.0      28.6       28.6       12.2       12.2
```

as an example for the first line of your data. Afterwards you use the given plotting command I gove above.

Comment: I understand basically I am trying to graph the performance of a SAN i collect the data into this file every minute. Each column represents this: the totalio, readpercentage, cachehitpercentage, currentkbpersecond,  maximumkbpersecond, currentiopersecond, and maximumiopersecond. So i could say that my x-axis was every second?

Comment: Great so I could add the time such as every 59 secs and plot each value against it...

Comment: Ok I managed to get my input file to be similar to this 
09:38 42.0 21.4 100.0 15.2 15.2 8.4 8.4, but my graph still not clear... :( here is what it looks like [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/chicom9/8178967136/)